# Python numpy - list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, numpy

I have a CSV file of the following format

```
86,1
15,2
19,3
52,4
15,5
13,6
18,7
20,8
49,9
266,10
```

For reproduciability, i have included the full [CSV file here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/vug94ykwk8a30e9/testdata3.csv/file). From column 1, I wanted to read current row and compare it with the value of the previous row. If it is greater, I wanted to take the difference of the current value from the previous one and store (`append`) the difference in a list. If the current value is equal to the previous row's value continue comparing. Let me make it clear.For example in the above sample record I provided, the third row (`19`) is greater than the value in the second row (`15`) - so it will be (`19-15 =4`), the fourth row (`52-19 = 33`), etc.

Here is my simple approach using `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.read_csv("testdata.csv")
with open("testdata.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for i in reader:
        print (i[0])
        diffs=np.diff(i[0])
        increased_value=np.median(diffs[diffs>0])
```

However, I am getting the error `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`. How can I fix this error in order to solve the task I mentioned?

Comment: are there any empty lines in your csv file?

Comment: NO, there are NOT empty lines in the CSV file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a better way

```
df = pd.read_csv("testdata.csv", header=None)
df
     0     1
0   86     1
1   15     2
2   19     3
3   52     4
4   15     5
5   13     6
6   18     7
7   20     8
8   49     9
9   266   10

diffs = np.diff(df[0])
increased_value = np.median(diffs[diffs>0])
increased_value

17.0
```

Comment: This is awesome! However, if you print `diffs`, it gives `array([-71,   4,  33, -37,  -2,   5,   2,  29, 217])`. How can we keep the negative numberss out of the list? Because i want to keep a lit of ONLY the current value is greaten than the previous row's value.

Comment: `diffs = diffs[diffs > 0]` if you want to drop the negative values or `diffs[diffs < 0] = 0` if you want to set them to zero.

Comment: How about if I want to do it the reverse way? Meaning, when the current row value is `less than` the previous row value? I did it like this: `np.median(diffs[diffs>0])` but the array list values I am getting are `negative` numbers - `[-71 -37  -2]
-37.0`

Comment: `diffs = np.diff(df[0])*-1` returns` [  71,   -4,  -33,   37,    2,   -5,   -2,  -29, -217]`
`np.median(diffs[diffs>0])` should return `37.0`

Is this what you were hoping for?

Comment: @AnanayMital, NO - the increasing part as you did it in your answer is correct. But I was trying to do the opposite of the question I asked - what happens if we wanted to do it when the current value is `smaller` than the previous value? For this (the reverse part), I was expecting to get `[-71 -37 -2]` and a median value of  `-37.0`.

Comment: yeah so that's just `np.median(diffs[diffs<0])`. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas [`s.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
data = StringIO("""86,1
15,2
19,3
52,4
15,5
13,6
18,7
20,8
49,9
266,10""")

df=pd.read_csv(data,header=None)

m1=df[0].diff().fillna(0)
#m1[m1>0].tolist()
#[4.0, 33.0, 5.0, 2.0, 29.0, 217.0]
m1[m1>0].median()
#17.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `np.diff()` expects a list like input, and what you are passing is an integer. That's the reason it is failing

Answer (score 0):

We technically don't need `numpy`

```
from statistics import median
from operator import itemgetter, lt, sub

first = itemgetter(0)
nums = []

with open('testdata.csv', 'r') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    for line in reader:
        nums.append(int(first(line)))

res = [abs(sub(*t)) for t in zip(nums, nums[1:]) if lt(*t)]

[4, 33, 5, 2, 29, 217]

median(res)

17.0
```

Comment: But using numpy, as shown by Ananay Mital, is in 99% of the cases preferable over using lists for numeric data.

Comment: it depends on the use-case but saying 99% of cases is an over-reach, this small data is trivial, we can agree to disagree

Comment: This is great but the line `res = [abs(sub(*t)) for t in zip(nums, nums[1:]) if lt(*t)]` says `Invalid syntax` on Python3

Comment: @aws_apprentice, where is the `5` in the list `[4, 33, 5, 2, 29, 217]` coming from? I am confused. If i do it manually, i get 5 values instead.

Comment: @Brown the sample data you provided has 13 and then an 18, hence the 5

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

is [np.diff()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) taking the input like array or list.

Like

```
arr = []
df = pd.read_csv("testdata3.csv")
df
with open("testdata3.csv", mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for i in reader:
#         print(i[0])
        arr.append(int(i[0]))

diffs=abs(np.diff(arr))
increased_value=np.median(diffs[diffs>0])
```

Comment: How about if I want to do it the reverse way? Meaning, when the current row value is `less than` the previous row value? I did it like this: `np.median(diffs[diffs>0])` but the array list values I am getting are `negative` numbers - `[-71 -37  -2]
-37.0`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've got is when you try to run np.diff, the default dtype for your array is dtype U3 which means the values in your array are not numbers which means a conversion is required. Try the following:

```
with open("test_data.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f) ## no need for delimiter if your delimiter is ','
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row[0])

## ensure that you convert your data into numpy array with appropriate data type 
## before carrying out any mathematical operations 

np_array = np.array(data, dtype=np.uint8) 
np_diff = np.diff(np_array)
np_median = abs(np.median(np_diff[np_diff > 0]))

print(np_median)
```

If you have to do this regularly, then you can always wrap this round a method. Give this a try.

Comment: How about if I want to do it the reverse way? Meaning, when the current row value is `less than` the previous row value? I did it like this: `np.median(diffs[diffs>0])` but the array list values I am getting are `negative` numbers - `[-71 -37  -2]
-37.0`

Comment: Are you expecting your result to be positive at all times?

Comment: Yes, I am expecting all my results to positive.

Comment: I've just made an update to include abs in the np_median variable which will make all results positive.

Comment: it prints the whole list `array([185,   4,  33, 219, 254,   5,   2,  29, 217], dtype=uint8)` which I don't think is right. For the increasing part, it should print only `[4, 33, 5, 2, 29, 219]` instead. The question I asked in my first comment to your answer should also print `[-71 -37 -2]`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just tried using an ordinary list containing your numbers i.e. data = [(86,1),(15,2),(19,3),(52,4), (15,5), (13,6), (18,7), (20,8),(49,9),(266,10)] and then looped through to get the list a = [86, 15, 19, 52, 15, 13, 18, 20, 49, 266]. I then converted this to numpy array then apply diff to get array([185, 4, 33, 219, 254, 5, 2, 29, 217], dtype=uint8). From this point I used abs(np.median(np_diff[np_diff > 0])) which gives me 33.0. For your comment on current value being less than previous value you will need to sort your data i.e. sorted(data).

Comment: the diffs[diffs > 0] is only a filter and doesn't actually tell you if the current row value is less than the previous row value. You will need to do a loop for that.